# retrieving items from JSON using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 app. I've got the JSON below. What I need is to be able to retrieve the INDEX of the particular item that has a passed CS value. The CS Value will be passed in the ViewBag, the JSON is also being passed in the ViewBag in the factory function below.

```
CDlg.factory("RS", function () {
    var rs = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.jsonCR);
    return rs;
});
```

This is the returned rs:

```
[
   {
      "CS": "AK",
      "CLL": "LN",
      "CTC": [
         {
            "LT": null,
            "CTID": 227322,
            "Hors": 8,
            "Units": 8,
            "Price": 8,
            "CEE": 0
         }
      ]
   },
  {
      "CS": "TX",
      "CLL": "LN",
      "CTC": [
         {
            "LT": null,
            "CTID": 219848,
            "Hours": 8,
            "Units": 8,
            "Price": 6,
            "CEE": 0
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "CS": "UT",
      "CLL": "LN",
      "CTC": [
         {
            "LT": null,
            "CTID": 219928,
            "Hours": 8,
            "Units": 8,
            "Price": 8,
            "CEE": 0
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "CS": "VA",
      "CLL": "LN",
      "CTC": [
         {
            "LT": null,
            "CTID": 220041,
            "Hours": 8,
            "Units": 8,
            "Price": 0,
            "CEE": 0
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "CS": "VT",
      "CLL": "LN",
      "CTC": [
         {
            "LT": null,
            "CTID": 220344,
            "Hours": 8,
            "Units": 8,
            "Price": 12,
            "CEE": 0
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This is the scope variable I need to populate:

```
$scope.selectedCS = ?????
```

If I pass in "TX, I need it to return the full object:

```
  {
      "CS": "TX",
      "CLL": "LN",
      "CTC": [
         {
            "LT": null,
            "CTID": 219848,
            "Hours": 8,
            "Units": 8,
            "Price": 6,
            "CEE": 0
         }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: have you consider using ng-repeat and filter ? please see here:http://jsbin.com/qahal/4/edit

Comment: It is to set a scope variable not be reflected in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate and check:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
    if (rs[i].CS == passedInValue) {
        return rs[i];
    }
}
```